# Get the parent element when clicking on SVG

Tags: reactjs, svg, onclick

I'm trying to get the parent element of an SVG element in my to react component. 
but each time the e.target is different... it could be the path element the circle element and so go on and on. 
How can I solve it? (I'm trying to create a tab bar to each post )

```
const handleNav = (e) => {
console.log(e.target
 }

<div className='tab-nav-container'>
      <div className='tab active' onClick={handleNav}>
        <HomeIcon /> // SVG ELEMENT
        <p>Home</p>
      </div>
      <div className='tab' onClick={handleNav}>
        <ContentIcon /> // SVG ELEMENT
        <p>Likes</p>
      </div>
      <div className='tab' onClick={handleNav}>
        <CommentsIcon /> // SVG ELEMENT
        <p>Search</p>
      </div>
      <div className='tab' onClick={handleNav}>
        <ProfileIcon /> // SVG ELEMENT
        <p>Profile</p>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: e.target.parentNode perhaps? (or parentElement)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I presume you mean you have nested SVG circles

```
> SVG
  > GROUP
    > CIRCLE
```

You can get the SVG with `event.target.closest("SVG")`

MDN: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/closest